# Mean-field approximation in quantum all-to-all connected Ising model

Tags: ising-model, mean-field-theory

I was struggling on a topic, namely the application of the mean-field approximation to the Ising model where all spins are connected to each other. In literature and internet I just find the mean-field approximation for the nearest neighbour Ising model. I hope you can help me either by providing literature I haven't seen or direct help.

The Hamiltonian for the **all-to-all connected** quantum Ising model of interest reads
$$
\mathcal{H}_p(t)=-\dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j \neq i} J_{ij}(t) \sigma_i^z \sigma_j^z - \sum_i h_i(t) \sigma_i^z
$$
where the summation goes over all possible two-body interactions between spins on sites $i$ and $j$, respectively, (the $\dfrac{1}{2}$ in front of the sum takes double summation into account) and the longitudinal field and interactions are time dependent.

Applying the mean-field approximation for the nearest neighbour case, literature says that the modulated - or effective - magnetic field reads
$$
h_{i,\textrm{mod}}(t)=h_i+2J_im^z(t)
$$
where $J_i$ is the average interaction strength between the nearest neighbours of site $i$ and $m^z(t)$ is the time-dependent average magnetisation.

So far, so good. I could derive this by applying 
$$
\sigma_i^z=\langle \sigma_i^z \rangle + \delta \sigma_i^z=m^z+\delta \sigma_i^z
$$
where the decoupled interaction $\sigma_i^z \sigma_j^z=-(m^z)^2+m^z(\sigma_i^z+\sigma_j^z)+\delta \sigma_i^z \sigma_j^z \approx -(m^z)^2+m^z(\sigma_i^z+\sigma_j^z)$ when we assume the fluctuations to be very small.

Now my two questions are:
1. What is the average magnetisation $m^z(t)$? In the case of $\pm 1/2$ spin, shouldn't it be just 0?
2. How does this modulated longitudinal field and mean-field Hamiltonian look like in the all-to-all case? Should I add all spins to get the average $J_i$ as $J_i=\sum_j Jij$? Or is there any physical reason, why nobody considers the mean-field approximation in the all-to-all connected case?

I am very happy for any help and thank you much in advance!

Comment: I think as described the model does not make sense in the large N limit, as the interaction term scales like N^2 vs. the on-site term which scales like N.  You would have to divide the interaction term by N and consider the large N limit.  This is also known as the Lipkin-Meshkov-Glick model.  (Or let me ask constructively: Do you have some references where the model as you write it is being studied?)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I just saw your post, so I am sorry for my late response. I agree that in the thermodynamic limit, this mean field approximation does not work at all, as you described due to the $N^2$ scaling, probably also the ansatz with small fluctuations is not valid anymore. I have no references where this was studied (that's why I asked). Also in literature about renormalization group or phase transitions (i.e. Nigel Goldenfield, Lectures on phase transitions and the renormalization group, just to name one,or papers) they just considered the nearest neighbor examples.

Comment: As I said, there is Lipkin-Meshkov-Glick.

Comment: @A. Hartmannm, mathematically  case of all-to all connections with constant coupling constant and constant external field means complete graph, it's partition fumction can be simply wrights (see answer to the question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299304/a-family-of-polynomials-whose-zeros-all-lie-on-the-unit-circle